# Databricks Pandas

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to append a header to a csv/text file in azure databricks . I am trying to read contents of file into string, append the header and rewrite.

```
 fileContent = dbutils.fs.head(file_path)
        fileContent = new_first_line + fileContent
        dbutils.fs.put(file_path, fileContent, overwrite=True)
```

However dbutils.fs.head returns only [Truncated to first 65536 bytes]

Is it possible to use Pandas fs to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe api to add column.
Use below code.

```
import pandas as pd
new_first_line = "Id,fname,lname"
df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/sample.csv",header=None)
display(df)
df.columns=new_first_line.split(',')
display(df)
```

[image]

Next write the file.

```
df.to_csv("/dbfs/fresult.csv",index=False, header=True, mode='w')
dbutils.fs.head("fresult.csv")
```

[image]

Or you can use below.

```
with  open('/dbfs/sample.csv', 'r') as original:
    data = original.read()
with  open('/dbfs/fresult1.csv', 'w') as modified:
    modified.write(f"{new_first_line}\n" + data)
    
print(dbutils.fs.head("fresult1.csv"))
spark.read.option("header","true").format("csv").load("dbfs:/fresult1.csv").show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi  @JayashankarGS,

Comment: Yes. @FunMatters

Comment: Tks for your time. Unfortunately Pandas in Azure Databricks has some limited functions. Example the .open is not supported. I have managed to overcome this using spark dataframes. I have created a new question with a new problem encountered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111631/databricks-dataframe-is-creating-multiple-files-per-write-file-in-a-separate-dir

Comment: what is the error you facing when you use `with open()`.

Comment: 'FSHandler' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: Like how you tried the code? you need to use `with open()` as given above.
Can you provide your code used.

Comment: Apparently it is a known problem. 

def insertFirstLineInFile2(file_path):
    with  open(file_path, 'r') as original:
        data = original.read()


# Loop through the list of files and read/print the first line
for file_info in file_list:
   insertFirstLineInFile2(file_info.path)
   

Seen here: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/i-am-trying-to-read-csv-file-using-databricks-i-am-getting-error/td-p/12499/page/4

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dbfs:/mnt/vvvvvvvv.csv'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
     85 # Loop through the list of files and read/print the first line
     86 for file_info in file_list:
---> 87    insertFirstLineInFile2(file_info.path)
File <command-2380294370792371>:40, in insertFirstLineInFile2(file_path)
     39 def insertFirstLineInFile2(file_path):
---> 40     with  open(file_path, 'r') as original:

Comment: If your are using spark context you need to use path like `file:/file_path` from root filesystem or `dbfs:/` from dbfs but normlly working with python it is `/dbfs/file_path`. 
So print those file paths and prefix them with one of the above protocal.Just provide any one of the file path in `file_list`